# Why is the `ORDER BY RAND()` statement not working in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

I have a database where I save information about my products. I use a query for getting those products from my table. The query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock > 0 ORDER BY RAND();
```

This query returns all the products that have `stock > 0` in a random order, and it works ok. However, now I want to get those products with `stock = 0`, but I want them to appear at the end of the query (also in a random way but always after products that have `stock > 0`). So I tried a new query which looks like this:

```sql
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock > 0 ORDER BY RAND()) 
UNION
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock = 0 ORDER BY RAND());
```

...this query returns the zero-stock products at the end, but it seems to ignore the `ORDER BY RAND()` statement and I always get them in the same order. So my question is: **how can I get a random response from the query mantaining the condition of zero-stock products at the end?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `UNION`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
ORDER BY stock = 0, RAND();
```

The condition `stock = 0` in the `ORDER BY` clause makes sure that the zero-stock products are placed last and the 2nd level of sorting with `RAND()` randomizes the rows in each of the 2 groups.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b7f9d7/6)

Comment: A more elegant solution than mine ;-)

Comment: Thanks! It was simplier than I though

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement to create a field to order by

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `stock` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`product`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `stock`, `product`) VALUES
  ('1', '10', 'Timber'),
  ('2', '12', 'Nails'),
  ('1', '0', 'Glue'),
  ('1', '0', 'Left handed wrench.');
```

And run

```
SELECT stock, product, case when stock > 0 then 1 else 2 end as SetOrder
FROM products 
ORDER BY SetOrder, RAND()
```

Gets you

> stock  product SetOrder
> 10 Timber  1
> 12 Nails   1
> 0  Glue    2
> 0  Left handed wrench. 2

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b7f9d7/5)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Interesting approach

Comment: @AlexSp3 An approach more useful if you have multiple conditions to order by, as you can have multiple conditions in the case statement.